# Insert multiple table but same columns name

Tags: mysql

How to write sql code insert multiple table but same columns name

```
-------------------       -------------------
|      table      |       |     tableTH     |
|-----------------|       |-----------------|
|id(AI)           |       |id(AI)           |
|name             |       |name             |
|address          |       |address          |
-------------------       -------------------
```

This code not working, How can i do

```
INSERT INTO table,tableTH (name,address) VALUES ('aaa','bbb');
```

Answer (score 1):

What about executing 2 statements (possibly inside of a transaction)?:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table   (name,address) VALUES ('aaa','bbb');
INSERT INTO tableTH (name,address) VALUES ('aaa','bbb');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: website has more than 3 language, one table to one language

Comment: It is not possible to insert into multiple tables with one statement, you have to use one statement pr. table